# C# dot net web service for alerts

Tags: c#

I want to create a C# dot net web service that will be checking for alert messages from a certain table in sql and then it sends the alert message to a certain URL e.g. I have a certain URL that I will use to pass the data like: `http://SMSAlerts/Message?msisdn=phoneno&text=message`, so here I will just pass the phone number and the message to the URL.
The question is, how will I Design the web service such that it will keep on checking that table for new alerts every time all by its self so that it can send to that URL? The table for the alerts is populated by another application.
Please help me know I can do this.

Comment: Hope this can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service should not do the work. It should just update a list of urls somewhere (i.e. on a database table).

Then you should develop a daemon (i.e. a windows service or a console application) that does the work polling data and using registered urls.